# I am using AJAX to get a javascript variable from the session but the parameters are coming back as null?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax

I am using the following code to try and get the javascript variable from the session through AJAX but every time I run the action there is nothing coming back in my controller but there is within my IE browser?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".GN").click(function() {
        var gnval = $(this).html();
        alert(gnval);

        window.location = 'test.action' + gnval;
        var value = gnval;
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "test.action",
            data: {
                gnval: value
            }
        });

    });

});
```

my Java:

```
String groupName = request.getParameter("gnval");
```

Comment: What you want make here `window.location = 'test.action' + gnval;` ?

Comment: This is where I put the variable at the end of the URL to see if I could retrieve it from the URL but still not having much luck.

Comment: Try to make `window.location = '/'` in the JS console (Chrome or FF). Try to comment this string.

Comment: Still no luck :/ I want to try and get the variable without the URL if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

`<div class="GN" data-gnval="yourVal">yourVal</div>`

And Javascript:

```
$(".GN").click(function() {

        var yourVal = $(this).data('gnval');

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "test.action", // correct url ?
            data: {
                gnval: yourVal
            }
        });

 });
```